# How to start EKL using .NET

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana-5, logstash-file

How can we start `elasticsearch, kibana and logstash` using **C# code**.? And how to
provide dynamic log to **ELK** stash

Comment: Can you please explain, what are you trying to achieve? What you mean by start ELK stack by C# code. You can install ELK stack service you know..

Comment: @AmeyVaidya:- Hi Amey.. I am trying to run elasticsearch, kibana and logstash (EKL) using c# code. All these three (elasticsearch, kibana and logstash ) are now command based. for starting these three we need to open command prompt and fire command . `So i am trying to start these services through C# code`.